# What does "cmd" in PQcmdTuples stands for?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I know what's this function do, 
but I can't find out a mnemonic for "**cmd**" in it.
It wolud really helps me to remember this function name.
Maybe someone knows? :)

Comment: perhaps "command"? From the official docs: "PQcmdTuples Returns the number of rows affected by the SQL command."

Comment: Same reason `cmd.exe` is the Windows NT equivalent of MS-DOS's old `command.com` (where the `com` *also* stands for command, I believe, it being a command for working with commands...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL Reference Manual](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/postgresql/vol2/RetrievingResultInformationforOtherCommands.html) it means 'command'.

Answer (score 2):

"cmd" usually stands for "command"